# Correct permission for Laravel folders on server

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently about to deploy a Laravel app. One of my features is to generate a PDF and save the file in the storage folder. But the problem is, it only works when the storage folder has `777` permission. Of course that is a big security risk once it is deployed. How to I solve it? Because if I don't `777` permission, it returns a `Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Permission denied in ...` error.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**These permissions should be set to `770` on the storage folder.**

This will allow the owner of the directory (ideally the maintenance web admin) read/write/execute. And it will allow the web group (ideally the group that the maintenance web-admin and the web server user are both in) to have read/write/execute permission. The 0 means that other users have no permissions in the directory. The directory should be owned by the maintenance  web admin, with it's ownership group set to the web group.

Example

```
chown -R mywebadmin:www-data /var/www/html/mysite.com/
chmod -R 750 /var/www/html/mysite.com/ 
chmod -R 770 /var/www/html/mysite.com/storage
```

Result

- /var/www/html/mysite.com - Owned by `mywebadmin`, Group is `www-data`

  - Owner can write/read/execute
  - Group can read/execute
  - Others can do nothing
- /var/www/html/mysite.com/storage - Owned by `mywebadmin`, Group is `www-data`

  - Owner can write/read/execute
  - Group can write/read/execute
  - Others can do nothing

---

There is a useful [tool](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-750/) for generating these permissions if you have a hard time remembering them.

> Note: It is extremely dangerous to have write access for the web user in the directory. A better option would be creating a PHP script that changes it's headers for `Content-Type` to `application/octet-stream` and having the PHP script generate the file it needs interanally without writing to the file system.

Comment: Please correct the first command (chown). First comes the user:group and then the path.